# Liferay Solr integration

Tags: solr, liferay, liferay-6, solr4

I've integrated liferay with solr and the same is working fine. I've some unique requirement, though, which is yet to be implemented.

We've a requirement because of which we've to add additional fields in Solr schema for liferay. Consider, I've to add fields related to products. I don't want to mix the product details with liferay details as i might need to flush only product details and re-index later. Because of this, I've two options and I need possible approach for both, if possible.

1> I can create separate SOLR schema for Product related details and fetch search results from that schema. But I believe, liferay solr plugin is not giving feature to fetch data from more than one schema. If it does, I'd like to know how. We will be using liferay default search portlet and hence the products should be searchable from there along with other liferay stuffs, like blogs and users and orgs etc.
2> The one which we're following currently. We've modified liferay schema and added few more fields into liferay schema. The issue here is, I'm not able to search into product details with free form text keyword (like laptop). Because the default query getting generated do not include the fields we've added, it's not able to find the product results. But the results are found when I use faceted search (like productName:laptop).

I'd prefer first solution if it's possible to implement. If not, I can adjust with second as well. I'll be waiting eagerly for the solution.

Thanks,
Rikin

Comment: At least I've resolved 2nd poing by overwriting postProcessSearchQuery method in indexer class. This allows to add fields to search in.

Comment: Can you show me how you have resolved your 2nd point.?Thanks

Comment: Please share the version details of liferay and SOLR